# If Operator and Continue For

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, foreach, continue

I have simple loop:

```
For Each Pla As Player In Game.Players
    Dim JustForTest As String
    JustForTest = If(Pla.Name,  Continue For)
    Console.WriteLine(JustForTest)
Next
```

If the player's name is nothing, it should skip to the next item(or player), but I got this error at "Continue For":

> BC30201   Expression expected.

Of course I can use like this:

```
For Each Pla As Player In Game.Players

    If Pla.Name = nothing then
    Continue For

    end if
    Console.WriteLine(Pla.Name)
Next
```

But I'm just curious what I was doing wrong, or is it a bug in VB?

Answer (score 2):

The [`If Operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) expects an *Object* to be passed into it as arguments, not a control statement. It is meant to be an equivalent to the ternary operator you'll find in other programming languages. You are trying to assign the value `Continue For` to your `JustForTest` variable -- and that just doesn't make sense.

It's not a bug in VB, just you trying to use the operator for something it's not designed to do.

Comment: The `If` operator as used in his example, is actually a null coalesence operattor, not a ternary.  The ternary form has three arguments

Comment: @jmoreno you are correct. I've always thought of it as a shortcut to `If(x IsNot Nothing, x, y)`. Coalesce is a term we see often in Sql for example, but less so in other languages I use.

Comment: Null coalesence and nebcgodggeufcxje. Cntgpg mm ,umuo

Comment: @jmoreno just that, yes.

Comment: Sorry, I started to comment using my iPad and was interrupted...I was going to say that null coalescence and propogation are valuable ideas, that are prominent in sql, but valuable in other languages as well.  For instance the new ref?.property syntax for vb/c# is a welcomed addition of a null propogation operator.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to compare to the Nothing (null in C#) is to use the `Is` or `IsNot` comparers, like: `If obj Is Nothing Then`.  If your Name property is supposed to be a string then it is better if you use a String function like `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Your continue For looks correct according to the documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx#Anchor_4